How to run Single File Programs in Rust?
I'm trying using Rust in OI (Olympics in Informatics), which only allows submitting Single File Programs.
In C++, we can easily use g++ path/to/file.cpp -oout.exe; ./out.exe. But I haven't found a Cargo command to do that in Rust. The only way I found for now is by adding
[[bin]]
name = "problem_1"
path = "path/to/file.rs"

to Cargo.toml and run cargo run --bin problem_1.
But as I solve more problems, it will soon become super long (and the content is almost repetitive). Is there a better way?

Put the source in src/bin/problem_1.rs, then cargo run --bin problem_1 (no need to declare it in Cargo.toml). See https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html

@Jmb Since I already have a directory structure, can I customize src/bin?

@typed-sigterm not without going back to what you were doing and listing them manually. Only src/bin/ has auto-detection.

You may also be interested in something like rust-script.

You do not have to use Cargo, the equivalent to your C++ example would be to call rustc directly. It works exactly the same:
rustc path/to/file.rs -o out.exe; ./out.exe

(It's not clear which operating system or shell you are using, but for example in a Unix-like shell you would usually use && instead of ; to only run the executable if the compilation was successful.)

FYI, cargo-script is in the process of being integrated into cargo itself. It's already available for testing, and I'm sure the implementers would love if people tried it and reported any sharp edges.
https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/12207
